# NODE ACL Module generating 500 instead of 403

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-500, node-acl

I am using [Node_ACL](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl), for authorization purpose it is working fine but whenever any request gets denied it generates **500 Internal Server Error** but it should show **403 Access denied error**. I already looked into its proper installation and setting but I didn't find any solution.

I am using it with [Express js](http://expressjs.com/) as a middleware. I am not sure who is causing the **500 Internal Server Error**. I mean I have used Node-ACL as a middleware in Express js. Whenever a client makes any request the Node ALC authenticate it first and then give access to the particular resource. So when the authorization gets failed, the **500 Internal Server Error** is coming to the client from the server. So Express can also be the reason because it's middleware is getting failed. I am not sure what to do.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got a solution, the Node-ACL was working properly. We just need to add some code to our Express app.js (server) file. The code is:

```
// Error Handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500).send({message: err.message});
});
```

Add this code at the end of the file (just before `module.exports`)

Now I am getting a proper error code.